# lein java compiler not found issue when java-source-paths added

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I want to include some custom java classes in my clojure project. So I created a directory like `src/java/subclass` containing my java file. The clojure code is at `src/subclass`. I added `:java-source-paths ["src/java"]` to `project.clj`. But when I run `lein repl` I am getting the following error.

```
Java compiler not found; Be sure to use java from a JDK
rather than a JRE by modifying PATH or setting JAVA_CMD.
```

I am having JDK installed. `javac -version` gives `javac 1.8.0_91`. If I remove the `:java-source-paths` line `lein repl` runs fine. How can I include custom java files to my project?

Windows 7
Leiningen 2.7.1 on Java 1.8.0_91 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Update: I tried lein run with the clj-antlr [demo](https://github.com/aphyr/clj-antlr/tree/master/demo) project, but the same issue. So this issue is not specific to my project setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works when `JAVA_CMD` is added. [#2228](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2228#issuecomment-267109084)